# Need help in rospy programming

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I wish to program my robot such that whenever the Lidar detect an obstacle, a 'stop' will be printed every 1 second.
However, whenever I place remove the obstacle, the output will not stop printing 'stop'.

Can someone kindly help me in this programming?

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import ,LaserScan
import os


def stop():
            print('stop')
            time.sleep(1)

class obstacle_detector:

  def __init__(self):
    self.laser_scan_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/scan_raw",LaserScan,self.lasercallback)
         
  def lasercallback(self,data):
        angle = 285
        self.laser_scan = 10000000
        for x in range (90):
         if data.ranges[angle] <  self.laser_scan:
             self.laser_scan = data.ranges[angle]
         angle = angle + 1
         if self.laser_scan < 1.5:
              stop()
         else:
              print('go')

def main(args):
  ic = obstacle_detector()
  rospy.init_node('obstacle_detector', anonymous=True)
  try:
    rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372000/need-help-in-rospy-programming/) by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem lies here

```
    for x in range (90):    #  --> loop 90 times
     # --> check if range at specific angle is lowest visited so far
     if data.ranges[angle] <  self.laser_scan: 
         self.laser_scan = data.ranges[angle]
     angle = angle + 1  # --> increment angle

     # WITHOUT LEAVING FOR LOOP call stop() or print go
     if self.laser_scan < 1.5:
          stop()
     else:
          print('go')
```

This means you'd print either stop or go 90 times PER SCAN!
The indentation of the last if clause is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on 2021-02-18**:
Thank You. Never realize is my mistake on that part.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-02-19**:
great that this helps. Please mark the answer as correct (if it is) by clicking the checkmark next to it. thanks.